# Regular/continuous mapping

Tags: arcpy, dbf

We've a regular (daily/weekly) provincial mapping process that uses .dbf files created with SAS (software like R, SPSS). An ArcMap document .mxd file (relative path) has map layers (crops) joined to the .dbf file (with columns for different crop yields by township - to get updated township-level crop yields). A Python code (ArcPy Mapping) exports selected crop layers as PDF maps (template with specific formatting, labeling and symbology).

The .atx file created by ArcGIS isn't updating. Is it important that the .atx file to be updated as well? I'm not fully sure if the .dbf file is correctly updating the map. Removing the layer joins and rejoin with the updated .dbf file messes-up the styling and takes lot of time to get the correct styling... Wondering if this is the best practice for regular automated mapping, or please suggest.

Comment: Create layer with fixed symbology, import it every time

Comment: Thanks Felix, do you suggest that I import the symbology for each layer and then export specific layers to PDF? I've 5 crops and with each crop having a irrigated and dryland types, so 10 symbology.See: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/154734/why-is-arcpy-script-to-apply-symbology-not-working and http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s300000025000000

Comment: Might be useful: http://ianbroad.com/arcgis-toolbox-using-layer-file-update-layer-properties/ and http://ianbroad.com/download/script/UpdateLayerProperties.py